# Why calling invalidate() in HttpSessionListener doesn't give StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, listener, stack-overflow, httpsession

I have a `jsp` file and a `HttpSessionListener` to monitor `HttpSession` destroying activities.

**index.jsp**

```
<%
    HttpSession s = request.getSession();
    System.out.println("SID1 : " + s.getId());
    s.setAttribute("Key", "Value");
    s.invalidate();
%>
```

**SessionListener**

```
@WebListener
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        HttpSession s = se.getSession();
        System.out.println("SID2 : " + s.getId());
        System.out.println(s.getAttribute("Key"));
        s.invalidate();
        System.out.println("Session Destroyed");
    }

}
```

Now according to the above situation, sending a HTTP request to `index.jsp` should create a `HttpSession` and call it's `invalidate()` method, meanwhile the `HttpSessionListener` should catch the same `HttpSession` and call the `invalidate()` once again, and this process should repeat over and over again.

Which should eventually result in throwing a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. But I have got the the following output **without any errors.**

```
SID1 : A2751AE9E782A17380415B0078C9ED90
SID2 : A2751AE9E782A17380415B0078C9ED90
Value
Session Destroyed
```

I have tested it with both GlassFish and Tomcat servers, the result stays the same. Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Why should it throw a `StackOverflowError`? The [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate--) on `HttpSession.invalidate()` mention that it should throw `IllegalStateException` if *this method is called on an already invalidated session*. Maybe this is a quirk/bug of the specific application server you are using.

Comment: can you print request.getSession().isNew() after s.invalidate() in jsp and let us know the result?

Comment: The session is not invalidated on the first time. Take a look at the session ids. they are same. so it should keep calling invalidate again and again

Comment: @techtrainer in the `jsp` file?

Comment: yes in jsp file, as mentioned in comment.

Comment: @techtrainer request.getSession().isNew() returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is because session is already invalidated when you invoke `invalidate` method for the second time from `public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {...}`.

`Session.beginInvalidate()` returns `false` value in this case and this block is not invoked:

```
boolean result = beginInvalidate();

try {
    //if the session was not already invalid, or in process of being invalidated, do invalidate
    if (result) {
         //tell id mgr to remove session from all contexts
         _handler.getSessionIdManager().invalidateAll(_sessionData.getId());
    }
}
```

In particular,`_handler.getSessionIdManager().invalidateAll` invokes `SessionHandler.invalidate`, which invokes `SessionHandler.removeSession` which invokes `_sessionListeners.get(i).sessionDestroyed(event);`.

So in case if the session is already invalidated this scenario doesn't work.

Comment: If the session has been invalidated already, how come the attributes get printed in the output when called in the listener?

Comment: I don't understand this your last question. What's the problem? First time you invoke `s.invalidate();` from the JSP. It does all this sequence described in my answer. After that your `sessionDestroyed` is invoked where all printouts are performed. Then you call there `s.invalidate()` again, but it has no effect as at this moment session is already invalidated.